# What kind of cabbage is on my photo?

Tags: vegetables, cabbage, lettuce

I bought it very cheap during the closing of the grocery market. The seller said that it was some kind of lettuce, but it tastes like upper leaves of cabbage.

[image]

Comment: That's definitely a lettuce, not a cabbage. Cabbages are round.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears to be curly endive which is a lettuce. It is crisp and has a bitter flavor. [Dole Know Your Lettuce](https://www.dolesalads.com/Lettuce-101/Curly-Endive)

Comment: yes it is. crisp and bitter

Comment: Also known as frisée.

Answer (score 1):

I used to work in produce and at first glance, I thought this was a Bok Choy Cabbage, but I also believe it's the Curly Endive Lettuce.

Comment: Bok Choy looks *nothing even remotely like* the photo in the question.